# Can't list organizational units in GSuite domain using Python code

Tags: python, google-api-client

I am trying to list all the organizational units in my GSuite domain but I can't access correctly to the resource object. I get an HttpRequest object address as a result. This is my piece of code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from apiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets

import pickle
import os.path
import requests
import json

from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import run_flow


ID = "xyz"      # mycostomer id

scope = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly",
                 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.groups",
                 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member",
                 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user",
                 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.users.userKey",
                 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit"]

json_secret = "secret.json"
creds = None

if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)

if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            json_segreto, scope)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)

service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=creds)

ou = service.orgunits().list(customerId=ID)
print(ou)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please add what error you are experiencing